# How to bypass Exception Handling for specific routes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, exception, laravel-9

I am trying to build an installer such as if laravel catch PDOException of 1049, then it will redirect to a route that will enable the user to input database credentials. Later, I will write those to .env & run artisan command. But stuck at too many redirect error. Also I have a separate route file for this route with no middleware declared.

```
if ($exception instanceof \PDOException) {
   $error_code = $exception->getCode();
   if($error_code == 2002 || $error_code == 1049){
       return response()->redirectToRoute('installer');
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `installer` route also requires a database connection to work?

Comment: I was able to bypass it somehow without using the default web middleware group. But now it's not working. And on installer controller there is nothing to do with database connection at first, it will update the .env file.

Comment: Check your service providers and middleware too, make sure none of those needs to connect to the database

Comment: Thanks to you. Found the issue and resolved it. Though I used file as session driver but don't know why it requires database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue solved. Actually the problem was I had modified the kernel.php and brought

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

to protected $middleware from protected $middlewareGroup => web for session message handling with toastr. Just reversed them as it was and everything works fine.

**2nd Solution**
Just look at your .env `SESSION_DRIVER` value. Set it to file. Also you can update `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')` in your `config/session.php` for safety. By default, it's the default value. But in which application, I was working, someone changed it to database. That's why I was facing such issues.